# Laravel Return Issue

Tags: arrays, laravel, api, eloquent

Hey my stack overflow nerds, I needs some help not sure if Ive just hit a mental block but im having some issues with me return back on my query and was wondering if anyone can help me...

Here is my controller

```
    {
        $shopperId = auth()->guard('shoppers')->user()->id;

        $completedItems = $this->shopifyCartService->getCompleteItems($shopperId);
        if ($completedItems) {
            return $this->responseHelper->response(true, "All completed items", $completedItems, 200);
        }
        return $this->responseHelper->response(false, "No completed item / items", null, 401);
    }
```

This is my response helper

```
    public function response($successful, $message, $data, $code)
    {
        return response()->json(['data' =>
            [
                'successful' => $successful,
                'message' => $message,
                'data' => $data,
            ]
        ], $code);
    }
```

And here is my Eloquent Query

```
    /**
     * @param int $shopperId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCompleteItems(int $shopperId)
    {
        return ShopifyCart::where([
            ['shopify_shopper_id', '=', $shopperId],
            ['cart_complete', '=', 1],
        ])->get();
    }
```

Im having a issue on my return on $completedItems it looks like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "successful": true,
        "message": "All completed items",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "shopify_shopper_id": 19,
                "shopify_shop_id": 1,
                "variant_id": "3",
                "qty": "1",
                "cart_complete": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-07-30T13:37:58.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-30T14:07:08.000000Z",
                "user": {
                    "id": 19,
                    "token": "9BW31WKtW4palubBtiyw2fP8jVFsxle5",
                    "firstname": null,
                    "lastname": null,
                    "contact_num": null,
                    "add_number": null,
                    "add_address": null,
                    "country_id": null,
                    "email": null,
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "password": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-07-30T13:12:23.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-07-30T13:12:23.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "shopify_shopper_id": 19,
                "shopify_shop_id": 1,
                "variant_id": "4",
                "qty": "8",
                "cart_complete": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-07-30T13:38:00.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-30T14:57:00.000000Z",
                "user": {
                    "id": 19,
                    "token": "9BW31WKtW4palubBtiyw2fP8jVFsxle5",
                    "firstname": null,
                    "lastname": null,
                    "contact_num": null,
                    "add_number": null,
                    "add_address": null,
                    "country_id": null,
                    "email": null,
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "password": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-07-30T13:12:23.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-07-30T13:12:23.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "shopify_shopper_id": 19,
                "shopify_shop_id": 1,
                "variant_id": "4",
                "qty": "1",
                "cart_complete": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-07-30T15:01:16.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-30T15:04:22.000000Z",
                "user": {
                    "id": 19,
                    "token": "9BW31WKtW4palubBtiyw2fP8jVFsxle5",
                    "firstname": null,
                    "lastname": null,
                    "contact_num": null,
                    "add_number": null,
                    "add_address": null,
                    "country_id": null,
                    "email": null,
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "password": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-07-30T13:12:23.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-07-30T13:12:23.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However I dont want to have the **"data": [
{** I want it like **"data": {** instead any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

In your `getCompleteItems` function you are trying to `get()` all completed items this will return `"data": [ {` because it's an array of objects but if you want `"data": {` instead you have to do `first()` and this will return the first completed item, double check your logic for this before doing `first()`

Comment: That will only return the first entry I may have more

Comment: Indeed, the question is what will group the completed items ? there must be an array of something, array of arrays or array of objects.

Comment: I just want to return the objects - Ive updated the question with what it looks like on more then one

Comment: Ok, let's break it down the json format looks like `{"key": "value"}` your key is `data` and your value must be a single value it could be `string`, `integer` or `array` you want to return many objects as `value` like `{"key": "value1", "value2"}` this is not a valid json format `value1, value2` must be grouped into something an `array` like `{"key": ["value1", "value2"]}`